# Xamarin.iOS how can I localized storyboard and nib files

Tags: xamarin.ios, localization

how can I add new language at Xamarin.iOS

I follow this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/#Localizing_Storyboard_UIs) to add new language but I stuck in localization of StoryBoard and nibs

should I create these directories manually

[image]

I mean **Base.lproj** Directory and move my storyboard inside it , then create my language directory inside Resources and include `MainStoryboard.strings` file

and if yes how can I get all ids of my controls

Sample of what I am asking for

"SXg-TT-IwM.placeholder" = "nombre de la tarea";

should I do manually or there are away in Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create manually for the folder and files.For the id of all your controls, you will need to check inside your storyboard file->Properties pane->Widget->Localization ID. The following is images from Xamarin guide:
[image]